# Extra "$qqrv" appearing in symbols

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, fastmm

Delphi XE3. I'm using the JCL Error dialog and FastMM with FullDebug turned on in my application and getting "garbage" appended to the symbols in the stack traces (both JCL and FastMM):

```
    [74EA3D67] RaiseException
    [0041815D] FastMM4.TFreedObject.VirtualMethodError$qqrv
    [0054FEC5] Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.CMInvalidate$qqrr24Winapi.Messages.TMessage
```

when what I'd like is:

```
    [74EA3D67] RaiseException
    [0041815D] FastMM4.TFreedObject.VirtualMethodError
    [0054FEC5] Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.CMInvalidate
    [00548735] Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc
```

But *only* when the app is compiled for Release. When I compile for Debug the stack trace is "clean". Since I'm seeing the same sort of "garbage" in FastMM and JCL reports I don't think it's either library giving trouble.

And I'm saying "garbage" with quotes because the $qqv seems to be constant and the rest of the string varies from run to run.

I have checked (and rechecked) the map file and symbols settings and the JCL symbols and I can't see anything different in the settings.

EDIT:
Not surprisingly the underlying cause is the same, as FastMM is (I think) using JCLDebug to generate the stack traces ... so fix one, fix all.

Comment: Nothing is wrong still the meaning of this `$qqrv` mangling is a question.

Comment: I've found the article (translated from German) which explains mangling in Delphi. For example `qqr` means `register` calling convention - http://translate.google.com/translate?prev=hp&hl=en&js=y&u=http%3A//edn.embarcadero.com/article/27758&sl=de&tl=en&history_state0=

Comment: What's "wrong" is that the stacktrace is less readable that it could/should be, and as you say it seems to be deliberate name mangling. Thanks for the page link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the .map file parser of the JCL.

see
http://sourceforge.net/p/fastmm/discussion/443400/thread/82b024dc/

for the detailed thread and suggested fix.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your Release configuration doesn't include stack frames compiler option (by default, it doesn't). Without this information compiled into the executable, what the stack trace shows are the names of the runtime package exports. The solution is to compile in Debug mode, or turn on stack frames in the compiler options of your Release configuration.

Comment: I did just check and I *do* have stack frames on in Release (its a beta, so lots of debug left on)

Comment: Cannot check right now as I don't have JCL Debug installed here, but is debug info turned on, too?

Answer (score 0):

After looking into it all I conclude that this is *no* problem, just my misunderstanding and maybe a bit of stale code:

The $qqrv and the other text is all valid and potentially useful information so rather than find a way to remove it it would be better to learn how to use it. The links in the questions above give good basis for this work.